# webspeed-Refresh page on every submit?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge, webspeed

I am new to webspeed, and need to know (using HTML/Javascript) how to refresh the page after every submit button. There are three submit & cancel buttons.

On every submit of some input field, if the input field value is valid then only I should show some other input fields with submit and cancel buttons.

Again on submit of above, it should show some other fields.

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question. Is it one page with three forms and submits or three different pages with submits? What kind of input fields, and how do you validate? What are the "other fields" that should be shown? Add more information!

Comment: If you want to know how to do DOM manipulation with Javascript then this Question should be tagged with Javascript because it would not be related to OpenEgde and Webspeed.